# import/export data to csv file in progress 4gl

Tags: csv, progress-4gl

I have csv file. I need to read it. Find and display some data in database with it.
After, I need to export collected data to the csv output file.
Here is my code:

```
/**********  DEFINE TABLES  **********/
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE TT
    FIELD AAA20 AS CHAR
    .

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE RES-T
    FIELD CIF       AS CHAR label "номер клиента"
    FIELD NAME      AS CHAR label "имя клиента"
    FIELD TEL       AS CHAR label "телефон 1"
    FIELD TLX       AS CHAR label "телефон 2"
    FIELD FAX       AS CHAR label "сот. телефон"
    FIELD AAA20     AS CHAR label "номер счета"
    .

/**********  DEFINE QUERIES  **********/
DEFINE QUERY Q1 FOR TT, AAA, CIF.

/**********  DEFINE WIDGETS  **********/
DEFINE BROWSE B1 QUERY Q1 
/*FOR EACH AAA, EACH CIF OF AAA:*/
    DISPLAY CIF.CIF       label "номер клиента"
        CIF.NAME      label "имя клиента"
        CIF.TEL       label "телефон 1"
        CIF.TLX       label "телефон 2"
        CIF.FAX       label "сот. телефон"
        AAA.AAA20     label "номер счета" WITH 25 DOWN SEPARATORS
        .

DEFINE BUTTON BTN-EXIT LABEL "EXIT".

/**********  DEFINE FRAMES  **********/
DEFINE FRAME F1 
    B1 AT ROW 1 COLUMN 2
    BTN-EXIT AT ROW 1 COLUMN 1
        WITH NO-BOX CENTERED.

/**********  MAIN LOGIC  **********/
INPUT FROM VALUE("Education/TRIUMF.csv").
REPEAT:
    CREATE TT.
    IMPORT DELIMITER "," TT.
END.
INPUT CLOSE.

OPEN QUERY Q1 FOR EACH TT,
        EACH AAA OF TT,
        EACH CIF OF AAA.

OUTPUT TO VALUE("MYCSV.CSV").
FOR EACH RES-T:
    EXPORT DELIMITER "," RES-T
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.

ENABLE ALL WITH FRAME F1.
WAIT-FOR CHOOSE OF BTN-EXIT.
```

But, there are many problems. I'm new to progress 4gl. Can any one help?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to get multiple fields from each record - in that case you need to specify each field in your TT definition instead of a single field. Can you provide a line of input data so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: Try being specific about "many problems".  It's hard to solve problems that aren't stated.

Answer (score 4):

This is  what the help says about IMPORT:

**IMPORT statement**

Reads a line from an input file that might have been created by EXPORT.

Syntax

```
IMPORT 
[ STREAM stream | STREAM-HANDLE handle ]  
[ DELIMITER character ] 
[    record [         EXCEPT field  ... ]     | UNFORMATTED field   ]
[ NO-LOBS ]  [ NO-ERROR ].
```

Focusing on this row

```
[    record [         EXCEPT field  ... ]     | UNFORMATTED field   ]
```

Basic meaning:

You can use IMPORT either with an entire record (and possibly exclude fields from that record by using EXCEPT) OR to a specific field (of a record or a variable) using UNFORMATTED.

What you do is this:

```
IMPORT DELIMITER "," TT.
```

What this means is that Progress will read one line of the input source, delimit it using comma (,) and then put each delimited string into one field of the temp-table named TT.

In your case TT has only one field (aaa20). That field will contain the first delimited string from the file. If the file have more delimited strings on each row that data will be lost.

You can do two things:

1) Add more fields to the temp-table. That will populate those fields with more data. You don't need to change the import statement.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE TT
    FIELD AAA20 AS CHAR
    FIELD secondfield AS CHAR
    FIELD thirdfield  AS CHAR.
    /* etc and you most likely want other names */
```

2) Import the entire row into the field (and thus removing the delimiter). This will put the entire row into the same field (AAA20). Most likely this is NOT what you want to do. AAA20 of TT will then contain the entire row (with comma separators and all else).

```
IMPORT UNFORMATTED TT.
```